# UI controls disappearing during run time

Tags: c#, ocean, petrel

I have a plug-in for petrel which is reading the data from XML initially and writing back to other XML file which are present in the same solution file, I have made a PIP file, when running this PIP file on other system UI controls are vanishing. Is this anything to do with the XML, does PIP holds the XML files or what else could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but what you've written is a bit confusing in the context of an Ocean for Petrel plug-in.

Your plug-in can certainly read and write information to and from xml files, but what does the location of the xml file in your Visual Studio solution file have to do with it? Or am I assuming you meant Visual Studio when you used the term "solution file" and that assumption is wrong.

The PIP file is the installer file for a plug-in that is read by the PluginManager of Petrel. You install the plug-in once with it on a machine that is running Petrel and the information needed to run the plug-in is registered in the PluginManagerSettings.xml flie that is parsed when Petrel is started. You don't run the PIP file as you state. Controls vanishing is not related to the PIP file, but to the structure of your code in the assembly (.dll) that contains your plug-in.

There is not enough information provided to give a useful answer on the nature of the problem you are having.